How to compose Django template snippets with Alpine.js to create reusable server-rendered components?

In short, what I’m struggling to achieve is creating a reusable Alpine component with its children defined in a Django template snippet.
Example with code that doesn’t work as intended — Carousel
I have this template structure: cities_page.html (template) / city.html (snippet) / carousel.html (snippet + Alpine) / carousel_item.html (snippet).
cities_page renders many cities and each carousel renders many carousel_items. All rendering happens server-side.
cities_page.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cities Page</title>
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.13.7/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
{% for city in cities %}
  {% include "myapp/snippets/city.html" with city=city %}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>

city.html
<div>
  <h2>{{ city.name }}</h2>
  {% include "myapp/snippets/carousel.html" with images=city.images %}
</div>

carousel.html
<div x-data="carousel">
  <template x-for="item in items" :key="item">
    <div x-html="item.itemHtml"></div>
  </template>
</div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
      Alpine.data(`carousel`, () => ({
        items: [
          {% for image in images %}
            {
              itemHtml: `{% include "myapp/snippets/carousel_item.html" with image=image %}`,
            },
          {% endfor %}
        ]
      }));
    });
</script>

carousel_item.html
<p>
  Item: {{ image }}
</p>

views.py
def cities_page(request):
    context = {
        "cities": [
            {
                "name": "London",
                "images": ["london1.jpg", "london2.jpg", "london3.jpg"]
            },
            {
                "name": "Paris",
                "images": ["paris1.jpg", "paris2.jpg", "paris3.jpg"]
            },
        ]
    }
    return render(request, "myapp/cities_page.html", context=context)

The reason why I want Alpine manage my carousel items is that I want to design interactions that manipulate these items. This could be methods like reverseOrder and removeItem.
The result of this is:
London
Item: paris1.jpg
Item: paris2.jpg
Item: paris3.jpg
Paris
Item: paris1.jpg
Item: paris2.jpg
Item: paris3.jpg
Note that London has images of Paris. The issue is that the script defined for Paris’s carousel overwrites the one for London.
My best attempt at fixing that is re-writing the carousel like this
<div>
  <template x-for="item in items" :key="item">
    <div x-html="item.itemHtml"></div>
  </template>
</div>

<script>
  (() => {
    const genRanHex = size => [...Array(size)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)).join('');

    const id = genRanHex(5)
    const currentScript = document.currentScript;
    const previousElement = currentScript.previousElementSibling;
    previousElement.setAttribute("x-data", `carousel${id}`)

    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
      Alpine.data(`carousel${id}`, () => ({
        items: [
          {% for image in images %}
            {
              itemHtml: `{% include "myapp/snippets/carousel_item.html" with image=image %}`,
            },
          {% endfor %}
        ]
      }));
    });
  })();
</script>

Note that I

Removed x-data
Generated a random ID and assigned it to the Alpine component name to make it globally unique
Set x-data with a script
Ensured the everything defined in the script doesn’t pollute the global scope (and other versions of that script included with each carousel instance) by wrapping it by an anonymous function

This feels like a really hacky way of building reusable components.
My question therefore is: What is the best practice in writing such components? Am I pushing things too far with Alpine and should I maybe consider using something like Vue/React to achieve such functionality?
Thank you for any help or for sharing any relevant resources.

I have something similar here. It may or may not be much help.
https://github.com/tochy97/djangoAPI
I am using a loader to call each Js content as needed by their path.
https://github.com/tochy97/djangoAPI/blob/main/static/components/common/js/loader.js
The index.js works as the initializer for everything.
https://github.com/tochy97/djangoAPI/blob/main/static/components/common/js/index.js

I get 404 when opening your links. Perhaps it's a private repo?

my bad try again

It works now, thanks. I see your code for loading scripts, but I can't see anything that would relate to the Alpine/Django component composition issue.
